# Using one source in designer and one in production.

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, windows-phone-7, designer

I'm developing a Windows Phone 7 app, where I databind an Image Source property, and use a converter to produce the image. Like so:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource MyImageConverter}}"></Image>
```

This works on the emulator, but crashes the designer, because MyImageConverter has dependencies on other code that is not instantiated by the designer. Is there any way I can make the designer ignore this attribute, or even better, can I specify another Source that is only used by the designer? I'm using Visual Studio 2010, if it matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by 'designer' you are referring to Blend or Cider (VS designer), you can use the following to find if you are in design mode or not

```
public static bool IsInDesignMode
{
    get
    {
        return DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject());
    }
}
```

Then wrap your code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The best and simple way is to use IsInDesignMode in .ctor of ViewModel:

```
if (IsInDesignMode) {
    //Design time data
} else {
    // production
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can assign the Source properties in code instead in designer and use conditional compilation:

```
#if DEBUG
  // assignments for development mode
#else
  // assignments for production mode 
#endif
```

Comment: This wouldn't show a difference between design and run time though. This is no compiler directive for this.